# Read JSON array Using JsonReader

Tags: android

I have developed an android application using JsonWrite and JsonReader. This is my Json array

```
[StudentListModel{rowId='1', userId='User1', userName='Vijil'}, StudentListModel{rowId='2', userId='User2', userName='Dhas'}]
```

This is my code

```
private ArrayList<StudentListModel> readUser(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        String rowId = null;
        String userId = null;
        String userName = null;
        StudentListModel model = null;
        ArrayList<StudentListModel> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("rowId")) {
                rowId = reader.nextString();
            } else if (name.equals("userId")) {
                userId = reader.nextString();
            } else if (name.equals("userName")) {
                userName = reader.nextString();
            } else {
                reader.skipValue();
            }
            model = new StudentListModel(rowId, userId, userName);
        }
        userList.add(model);
        reader.endObject();
        return userList;
    }
```

The above code returns the second list(below list) only not all.

```
StudentListModel{rowId='2', userId='User2', userName='Dhas'}
```

I have an error in looping section, please help me to come out this.

**Now I fixed With below code:**

```
boolean isRowAdded = false, isIdAdded = false, isNameAdded = false;
while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("rowId")) {
                rowId = reader.nextString();
                isRowAdded = true;
            } else if (name.equals("userId")) {
                userId = reader.nextString();
                isIdAdded = true;
            } else if (name.equals("userName")) {
                userName = reader.nextString();
                isNameAdded = true;
            } else {
                reader.skipValue();
            }
            model = new StudentListModel(rowId, userId, userName);

            if (isRowAdded && isIdAdded && isNameAdded) {
                userList.add(model);
                /**
                 * reset insitial status for next iteration
                 */
                isRowAdded = false;
                isIdAdded = false;
                isNameAdded = false;
            }
        }
```

Now working correct, but I don't know in later I face any issue?

Comment: The structure of the JSON code is INVAILD.Please check it by the following URL https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Just copy and paste your JSON code and check it in the above link

Answer (score 0):

You add model to the user list after parsing all array. So, you add only last value that you parse. Just move userList.add(model) call to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        if (name.equals("rowId")) {
            rowId = reader.nextString();
        } else if (name.equals("userId")) {
            userId = reader.nextString();
        } else if (name.equals("userName")) {
            userName = reader.nextString();
        } else {
            reader.skipValue();
        }
        model = new StudentListModel(rowId, userId, userName);

 userList.add(model);

    }
```

paste this code

Comment: i already tried this, and this will not solve my issue because each and every time userList will be update and this is the result [SocketResponseModel{requestToken='001', requestStatus='SUCCESS', responseList=[StudentListModel{rowId='1', userId='null', userName='null'}, StudentListModel{rowId='1', userId='h', userName='null'}, StudentListModel{rowId='1', userId='h', userName='j'}, StudentListModel{rowId='2', userId='h', userName='j'}, StudentListModel{rowId='2', userId='jj', userName='j'}, StudentListModel{rowId='2', userId='jj', userName='hjjk'}]}]

Comment: you can try GSON to parse you JSON have a look here https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html